# How do I convert a Python DataFrame into a NumPy array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Below is a snippet that converts data into a NumPy array. It is then converted to a Pandas DataFrame where I intend to process it. I'm attempting to convert it back to a NumPy array. I'm failing at this. Badly.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint

data = [
    ('2020-11-01 00:00:00', 1.0),
    ('2020-11-02 00:00:00', 2.0)
]
coordinatesType = [('timestamp', 'datetime64[s]'), ('value', '<f8')]

npArray = np.asarray(data, coordinatesType)
df = pd.DataFrame(data = npArray)

# do some pandas processing, then convert back to a numpy array

mutatedNpArray = df.to_numpy(coordinatesType)
pprint(mutatedNpArray)

# don't suply dtype for kicks
pprint(df.to_numpy())
```

This yields crazytown:

```
array([[('2020-11-01T00:00:00', 1.6041888e+18),
        ('1970-01-01T00:00:01', 1.0000000e+00)],
       [('2020-11-02T00:00:00', 1.6042752e+18),
        ('1970-01-01T00:00:02', 2.0000000e+00)]],
      dtype=[('timestamp', '<M8[s]'), ('value', '<f8')])
array([[Timestamp('2020-11-01 00:00:00'), 1.0],
       [Timestamp('2020-11-02 00:00:00'), 2.0]], dtype=object)
```

I realize a DataFrame is really a fancy NumPy array under the hood, but I'm passing back to a function that accepts a simple NumPy array. Clearly I'm not handling dtypes correctly and/or I don't understand the data structure inside my DataFrame. Below is what the function I'm calling expects:

```
[('2020-11-01T00:00:00', 1.000   ),
 ('2020-11-02T00:00:00', 2.000  )],
 dtype=[('timestamp', '<M8[s]'), ('value', '<f8')])
```

I'm really lost on how to do this. Or what I should be doing instead.

Help!

---

As @hpaul suggested, I tried the following:

```
# ...
df = df.set_index('timestamp')

# do some pandas processing, then convert back to a numpy array

mutatedNpArray = df.to_records(coordinatesType)
# ...
```

All good!

Comment: Look for a `to_records` method. Don't forget to read the docs.  You may be able specify `dtype` as you did originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the [`to_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html) approach mentioned in comments, you can do:

```
df.apply(tuple, axis=1).to_numpy(coordinatesType)
```

Output:

```
array([('2020-11-01T00:00:00', 1.), ('2020-11-02T00:00:00', 2.)],
      dtype=[('timestamp', '<M8[s]'), ('value', '<f8')])
```

---

**Considerations:**

I believe the issue here is related to the difference between the original array and the dataframe.

The shape your original numpy array is `(2,)`, where each value is a tuple. When creating the dataframe, both `df.shape` and `df.to_numpy()` shapes are `(2, 2)` so that the `dtype` constructor does not work as expected. When converting rows to tuples into a `pd.Series`, you get the original shape of `(2,)`.